# addEventListener on url in React Native Web

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-web

I am trying to have a function called on an event listener in React Native Web.

I have this code in my class constructor:

```
Linking.addEventListener('url', this.onOpenURL);
```

And then later on in my program, I use:

```
Linking.openURL(url);
```

This opens the URL in question, however the `this.onOpenURL` never runs.

Is there a way to make this happen specifically on React Native Web?

Comment: https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/issues/1650 the issue link to track the changes easier for others